# Making custom angular cdk-table DataSource with async pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I really want to incorporate the cdk-virtual-scroll. But with cdk-virtual-scroll table headers wont follow css sticky position property. So I came across a post describing custom scroll strategy.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-virtual-table-sticky-header?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In this example they extends the datasource.

Here they have hardcoded data.

```
  rows = Array(200).fill(0).map((x, i) => {
    return {name: 'name' + i, id: i, age: 27};
  });
```

Is there a way to get data from an http call and populate dataSource with the observable & unwrap those observables using async pipe in the template. (rather than hardcoding data in the component.ts file or subscribing to the data in componenet.ts file to achieve custom-scroll like the one above)?

Make http call to this end point :

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

Like this:

```
[dataSource]="dataSource | async"
```

Answer (score 1):

The table gets the data as an Observable from the DataSource by calling `dataSource.connect`. This function should return an Observable that emits the data to display. You don't need the AsyncPipe when using a DataSource.

Pass the initial data as an Observable to your DataSource and modify this data with RxJS operators in `dataSource.connect` before returning it. Terminate the  Observable in `dataSource.disconnect`.

Based on the stackblitz you provided this could be:

```ts
const PAGESIZE = 20;
const ROW_HEIGHT = 48;

export class GridTableDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  private initialData$: Observable<any[]>;
  private onDisconnect$ = new Subject<void>();

  offset = 0;
  offsetChange = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor(
    initialData$: Observable<any[]>,
    private viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport, 
    private itemSize: number
  ) {
    super();
    this.initialData$ = initialData$;
    this.viewport.scrollToOffset(0);
  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<any[] | ReadonlyArray<any>> {
    return combineLatest( // combine the scroll events with your initial data
      this.viewport.elementScrolled().pipe( // start with a currentTarget
        startWith({ currentTarget: this.viewport.getElementRef().nativeElement })
      ),
      this.initialData$.pipe(
        tap(data => this.viewport.setTotalContentSize(this.itemSize * data.length))
      )
    ).pipe(
      map(([event, initialData]: [any, any[]]) => { // map to visible data
        const start = Math.floor(event.currentTarget.scrollTop / ROW_HEIGHT);
        const prevExtraData = start > 5 ? 5 : 0;
        // const prevExtraData = 0;
        const slicedData = initialData.slice(
          start - prevExtraData,
          start + (PAGESIZE - prevExtraData)
        );
        this.offset = ROW_HEIGHT * (start - prevExtraData);
        this.viewport.setRenderedContentOffset(this.offset);
        this.offsetChange.next(this.offset);
        return slicedData;
      }),
      takeUntil(this.onDisconnect$)  // unsubscribe on disconnect
    );
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.onDisconnect$.next();
  }
}
```

Pass the http request as initial data to your custom DataSource.

```ts
this.dataSource = new GridTableDataSource(
  this.http.get<any[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"),
  this.viewport,
  this.itemSize
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-virtual-table-sticky-header-26g3j5

Comment: Thank You for helping.

But I would like to use it with async pipe. Each column in the table data has a separate filter. & I've set all the filters based on the async data. I just need to implement async pipe along with the cdk-virtual-scroll functionality with fixed header.

If there is a way to do this without subscribing in  the component , please suggest.

Comment: @SpeedCode You can't use the AsyncPipe with a DataSource and you don't need to. Just return the Observable you want to use with the AsynPipe from `dataSource.connect`. My solution isn't subscribing anywhere in the component. If you have multiple filters you can add them to the `combineLatest` Observable. Post the code with your filters if you have problems integrating them.

Comment: Oh. Okay. My bad. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to connect with you in the future? (in case if I need some help)